# Duration of audio file with Libvorbis for Android

Tags: android, audiotrack

I'm using [this library to read ogg files](https://github.com/vincentjames501/libvorbis-libogg-android) with Android.
Since I've been taking a look to the C++ code and Java code, I haven't seen the way to retrieve the duration or the number of PCM samples after decoded. It contains the class `AudioTrack` but I haven't been able to retrieve that data.

Is there any workaround I can do to see the duration?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the number of samples **n**, the samplerate **SR** and the number of channels **c**, the duration **t** in ms is:

```
t = (n * 1000 / SR) / c
```

Example:

> 123456 stereo samples at 44100Hz = 1399 ms
>
> 9000 mono samples at 8000Hz = 1125 ms

AudioTrack contains some getters to retrieve the samplerate and the number of channels in case you don't have this information. Since you got the decoded data, you should know the number of samples.